# (Kubernetes) Port forwarding from a NodePort port to a port outside its' range

Tags: kubernetes, port-forwarding

I have a pod that runs on Kubernetes on a local machine (My Mac) and is defined to be accessible via nodePort 30036

```
  - protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8081
    nodePort: 30036
```

I'd like to be able to access to this node using a port outside the ranges that were defined for nodePort usage (30000-32768). Something let's say like 8080.
What are my options?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As there is no information about the exact Kubernetes solution used, it could be hard to pinpoint the exact solution.

Assuming that there are 2 options:

- `Docker Desktop with Kubernetes`
- `Minikube`

Some solutions for them could be:

---

### Docker Desktop with Kubernetes

#### `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`

Your Kubernetes cluster can use `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` and get linked to your `localhost` (your Mac `localhost`).

You can check this by running following example:

- `$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx`
- `$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer`
- `$ kubectl get services`

```sh
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        10d
nginx        LoadBalancer   10.111.214.48   localhost     80:30032/TCP   77s
```

- `curl 127.0.0.1:80` / `curl kubernetes.docker.internal:80`

```html
<-- REDACTED --> 
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<-- REDACTED -->
```

> A side note!
>
> You can modify it further by using `--port` (port on your `localhost`) and `--targetPort` (port that is listening in your `Pod`)  parameters when using `$ kubectl expose ...`

#### Change the `NodePort` port range

You can follow this in-depth answer that will show you how you can modify your `kubeapi-server` to change the `NodePort` port range (by logging to Docker VM):

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: How to change the default nodeport port range on mac docker desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582980/how-to-change-the-default-nodeport-range-on-mac-docker-desktop)*

#### Use `Ingress` controller

You can also use an `Ingress` controller that will bind to your Mac's `localhost` and will allow you to use `Ingress` resource (it's mainly for `HTTP`/`HTTPS` but with some adjustments it can pass `TCP`/`UDP` traffic). Here you can find more information on that topic:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*

---

### Minikube

With `Minikube` there can be a lot of variation due to the `--driver` used.

#### Change the `NodePort` port range

Once again you can follow below answer to change the `minikube` `NodePort` port range:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: How to change the default nodeport port range on mac docker desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582980/how-to-change-the-default-nodeport-range-on-mac-docker-desktop)*

#### Use `metallb`

You can also use [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/) to allocate the addresses for your `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`.

The steps to do it would be following:

- `$ minikube start --driver=hyperkit`
- `$ minikube addons enable metallb`
- `$ minikube node list` (notice the IP address of your `minikube`)
- `$ minikube addons configure metallb` (put the allocated range near the `minikube` ip like:

  - `minikube ip`: `192.168.64.11`
  - `metallb start`: `192.168.64.100`
  - `metallb end`: `192.168.64.110`
- Create the workload and expose it with `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`
- `$ curl SVC_EXTERNAL_IP:PORT`

> A side note!
>
> `--driver=hyperkit` was used due to:
>
> > Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
>
> This message is related to the access of your `minikube` instance when using `--driver=docker` and it's limitations. You need to use `minikube service SERVICE_NAME` to access the `Service` (and the terminal must be running while you are at it).

---

> A side note!
>
> I'd reckon as a workaround measure you can also use a `$ kubectl port-forward`.

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services Networking: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*

Comment: Hello @pavel-zagalsky. Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?